# Identity Experience Framework : Is there any reference documentation?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to create custom policies for some of requirements. I am not able to find good documentation on Identity Experience Framework. Is there a reference guide that explains about technical profiles, user journeys, claim providers, relationship between them etc?

I looked at online documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom, but it is not helpful much.

Answer (score 5):

You can also refer to documentation that can be found in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/Documentation). This was drafted for the custom policies preview (known as the "Azure AD B2C Premium" service when this was written). Some of it is out-of-date but it does describe the high-level concepts and details the custom policy schema.

**15 Sep 18: UPDATE**

The official documentation for the Identity Experience Framework schema can now be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/trustframeworkpolicy.

Answer (score 3):

There are several. For learning to develop custom policies, we recommend [Gaining Expertise with Azure AD B2C](https://aka.ms/learnAADB2C), a course for developers. The later modules go into custom policies pretty extensively.

Comment: I see the same information as in the link I mentioned...It is consolidation of lot of msdn articles put together as guide..It doesn't explain the concepts or relationships etc I was looking for.